# angularjs getting rel attr of DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I recieve custom html from external souce with sanitize, a custom service I made to trust the html source

```
<div ng-click="clickOnBlockd()" ng-bind-html="customHtml | sanitize"></div>
```

But What I want to do is to get the link which located within the inner level of the html and open it to the new window. My DOM is like below.

```
$scope.customHtml =  <div id="wrapper"><div rel="http://google.com">Google</div></div>
```

It would be easy if I'm with jquery, but I've no clue how to do it with angularjs.

Comment: Do you have jQuery in the project already?

Comment: @tymeJV nah I wouldn't want to mix it with jquery.

Comment: Yeah if you don't already have it then don't include it (just making sure it wasn't already there) -

Comment: @tymeJV but how to solve my above problem?